# Infinite content loop carousel

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I made this pretty simple content loop-carousel component, but
the code seems too *"Iffy"* but Im not sure how I could make it better.

I tried to use the Switch expression, which makes it a bit more readable, but
I dont like the breaks in them.

here is the relevant js code:

```
data() {
    return {
      ...

      currentContentId: 0,

      content: [
        { id: 0, title: "title1", body: "description1" },
        { id: 1, title: "title2", body: "description2" },
        { id: 2, title: "title3", body: "description3" }
        
      ]
    };
  },

methods: {
    nav(e) {
      
      let loopLength = this.content.length - 1;
      
      if (e.target.parentElement.id === "nav__back") {
        if (this.currentContentId == 0) {
          this.currentContentId = loopLength
        } else {
          this.currentContentId--
        }
        
      } else {
        if (this.currentContentId == loopLength) {
          this.currentContentId = this.currentContentId - loopLength 
        } else {
          this.currentContentId++
        }
      }  
    }
```

html:

```
<div class="content">

    <a id="nav__back" class="content__arrow" @click="nav">
      <i class="material-icons">arrow_back_ios</i>
    </a>

    <div class="content__wrapper">
      <h1 class="content__heading">{{ content[currentContentId].title }}</h1>
      <div class="content__text">
        <p>{{ content[currentContentId].body }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <a id="nav__forward" class="content__arrow" @click="nav">
      <i class="material-icons">arrow_forward_ios</i>
    </a>
  </div>
```

[heres my codepen link (theres also a theme switcher, pay no mind to that)](https://codepen.io/Epsilon6/pen/yLjEQER?editors=0011)

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your code breaks when your id's are not in sequence. I wouldn't call them `id` then, but maybe `index` and if index, why even have them in the data structure (it is implied by the position in the array)?
- That `0` as magic number of first `id` also bothers me. Would be much better to initialize this id based of `contents[0].id`
- Your first `if` is there because you didn't want to create separate method for forward and back buttons. If you create 2 separate methods, code is shorter, cleaner and you get rid of the first `if`.
- Then your code is 2 methods with single `if-else`. Since you are basically just moving this `index` between `0` and `contents.length`, you can instead use `%` module and eliminate that if too. Something like:

```
this.currentContentId = (this.currentCOntentId + 1 + loopLength) % loopLength
```

Another possibilities in case you want to keep ifs:

- I would extract conditions of your ifs into methods like `isOnFirstItem` or `isOnLastItem`, that increases readability greatly for someone who never saw the code before.
- Rather than modifying `currentContentId`, I would create explicit methods like `goForward`, `goFirst`, `goPrevious`, `goBack`.

Comment: I don't agree about the need for extracting methods (see my answer for how to make that easier), but the rest of the answer is definitely worth a +1

Comment: I assume the "can go negative" you're thinking about is if it goes above 2147483647 (a.k.a Integer.MAX_VALUE). Let's hope there's not that much content on this site, otherwise I think there's other issues to be addressed...

Comment: I meant when going negative (in this case only coming from 0 to -1), the result can be negative. I actually rephrased, changed the formula and removed it to make it less confusing.

Comment: I must insist that splitting in 2 methods would be better. Reasons being better readability, bigger flexibility (why does code functionality has to be bound to html and determined by parent element id?). Although your math is pretty neat to sum it all up into single expression, this doesn't justify putting it all in one place.

Comment: I guess a `goForward` and `goPrevious` that in turn calls `changeOffset` or something doesn't hurt.

Comment: Do note that in the original code, `loopLength` is not actually the size of the array, but rather the last index in the array.

Answer (score 2):

This part:

```
  if (e.target.parentElement.id === "nav__back") {
    if (this.currentContentId == 0) {
      this.currentContentId = loopLength
    } else {
      this.currentContentId--
    }
    
  } else {
    if (this.currentContentId == loopLength) {
      this.currentContentId = this.currentContentId - loopLength 
    } else {
      this.currentContentId++
    }
  }
```

Is essentially moving `currentContentId` forward or back by 1, with wrap-around.

Note that this:

```
if (this.currentContentId == loopLength) {
    this.currentContentId = this.currentContentId - loopLength 
}
```

Is equal to: (because we know already that `this.currentContentId == loopLength`)

```
if (this.currentContentId == loopLength) {
    this.currentContentId = 0
}
```

So the whole thing can be written as:

```
let offset = e.target.parentElement.id === "nav__back" ? -1 : 1
this.currentContentId = (this.currentContentId + offset + this.content.length) % this.content.length
```